# id & name changed every time WebDriver runs

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a Java WebDriver code to send SMS from way2sms.com but I'm failing to insert mobile no in the box.

Below is the fraction of page from which I'm trying to insert any no in text box, I've already tried `className(), cssSelector(), id(), name();` but nothing's working. Actually the problem is `id="tQTSajQW"` and `name="tQTSajQW"` change every time I run my WebDriver program.

```
<p id="p1">
    <input id="textfield2" class="inp" type="text" style="width:30px; color:#333; background: #e0e0e0;" name="textfield2" value="+91" readonly="readonly">
    <input id="tQTSajQW" class="inp" type="text" value="" onchange="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeydown="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeyup="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" maxlength="10" onblur="if(this.value==""){ this.placeholder="Mobile Number";this.style.color="#293f46;"}" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="tQTSajQW" style="">
    <img id="locMob" alt="Find Mobile Location" src="http://sc1.way2sms.com/w2sv5/images/locate-mobile.gif" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 86px; left: 240px;" onclick="javascript:locateMob();">
</p>
```

Is there any way we can do that, apart from the above methods?

Comment: You tag in `<p>` aren't closed

Answer (score 0):

Tie it with CSS selectors or xPath expression to other elements around the problematic one.

For instance:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@id='p1']/input[2]"));
```

Or if there are more changes to the page, then just get the children of the `<p>` and loop them through:

```
WebElement paragraph = driver.findElement(By.id("p1"));
List<WebElement> inputs = paragraph.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

for (WebElement input : inputs) {
  if ("Mobile Number".equals(input.getAttribute("placeholder"))) {
    // do your tricks
  }
}
```

Comment: True, but OP didn't say the page would change that much, however edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: Tried the below code as you mentioned, but program keeps on running (webpage keeps loading). It couldn't insert the value in mobile no box.
WebElement paragraph=driver.findElement(By.id("p1"));
  List<WebElement> inputs=paragraph.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
  for(WebElement input:inputs){
   if ("Mobile Number".equals(input.getAttribute("placeholder"))) {
    input.sendKeys("9818048682");
   }
  }

More details:
*body->form->divs->p->input->Mobile Number*